# JQuery Fancybox popup box

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to use jquery and fancybox to popup a page with a gravity forms  in it.  I've followed the following directions:

http://www.gravityhelp.com/creating-a-modal-form-with-gravity-forms-and-fancybox/

Everything seems to be working properly, with the exception of the jquery part.  It does not open in a popup box on the page.

Here is a link

http://whistlerworks.com/clients/nawreck/site/

It is the first box on the bottom left that says Our attorneys have recovered millions.  when you hover over the box and click it should pull up the popup box but instead it just redirects you to the page.

Thanks

Comment: you are loading jQuery twice when you only need a single instance ... preferably the latest version.

Comment: I'm a jquery novice so....  I'm not seeing where I have it loaded twice.

Comment: You don't need jQuery knowledge but a basic HTML knowledge ...in the `<head>` section of your document you load jQuery with `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>` but you have two versions (v1.4.1 and 1.7.2), look for them.

Comment: I have plenty of html knowledge, but there is no  1.7.2 version in the header.php file.  I added <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>  Where are you seeing the second version?  Is it possible that it is somewhere else other than in the head tags?

Comment: just here http://whistlerworks.com/clients/nawreck/site/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2 just after this <!--Google fonts--> comment in your `<head>` section

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use 2 versions of jQuery, and as from jQuery 1.7 delegate has been replaced by on().
So just include ONE jQuery script before Fancybox, whose version is less than 1.7 and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all these 3 lines;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.0.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.0.pack.js"></script>
```

Comment: I do, I have the following code.  I changed the path of the fancybox because when I dowloaded it the path did not have a version type after it.  The code I have in the head sections is as follows: